# Table view cell on swipe "Delete" button gets covered

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am running Xcode 6.4 developing in Swift.

I want to be able to swipe the cell to delete messages. This is the function I have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        //Delete messages here
    }
}
```

This is simply enabling the swipe function of the cells. However, I only see "Delet", without the last "e" at the end. Is this a bug?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Are you using `UITableViewCell` or a custom class?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry, should've thought about that before posting. Updated with screenshot.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam, I'm using UITableViewCell.

Comment: What does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` look like?

Comment: It's really long because I have set a bunch of other stuff in there. But isn't that unrelated to my `commitEditingStyle` function? If you want it, I can email it to you (I can't message you on SO yet).

Comment: It's the same for portrait and landscape?

Comment: How did you create the tableViewController ? Interface builder or code ? Did you happen to set yourself or change the width of the tableView ?

Comment: Did you use autoLayout?